# swift not sure on layoutIfNeeded setNeedsUpdateConstraints or updateConstraints setNeedsLayout

Tags: ios, swift

I am calling an API. Depending on what json data I get back I am modyfing my View Controller in `viewDidLoad()` in order to change my views design to display the given data best way possible.

What I do is to hide some uiViews and set their constraints to be .active = false but also changing some of the constraint by eg:

```
let noCButton = NSLayoutConstraint(item: aListTop, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: aListBottom, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(noBidButton)
```

Then just before closing viewDidLoad() where I change/disable some constraints I call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`

So my question now is,

If I change/disable some constraints or hide a uiview, should I always call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` afterwards?

Also, do I need to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` right after every change or can I just simply call it once before closing viewDidLoad()?

I dont get any errors in my console either way, but I just want to make sure I am doing it the right way. I also noted functions like `updateConstraints` but layoutIfNeeded seems to work, tho im not 100% sure about the difference

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call `view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`. After `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` should be called automatically. This should be all you need to do at this moment.

If you need to force the view to update immediately call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`, if you want to make a set of changes and then have them all applied at the next layout pass just call `view.setNeedsLayout()` at the end of all your changes.

Comment: Why cant I just run view.layoutIfNeeded()? It doesnt output any errors right now. And since I am only making a change once I do it in viewDidLoad

Comment: Sorry didnt see your edit. Ok thanks! Then I will just call view.setNeedsLayout() in viewDidLoad? Since I am making my changes there and I dont want to display the view until I have set my changes

Comment: You may not even need to call setNeedsLayout because that will take place after viewDidLoad anyway.